# How can I setup LookAndFeel Files in Java?

Tags: java, swing, qt, gtk, look-and-feel

I need to setup LookAndFeel Files in JDK 1.6.
I have two files:

1. napkinlaf-swingset2.jar
2. napkinlaf.jar

How can I set this up and use it?

I would like a GTK look and feel OR Qt look and feel, Are they available?

Comment: Can you please be more clear? These 2 files, do you have the source or are they just binaries you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class name for Naplin is `net.sourceforge.napkinlaf.NapkinLookAndFeel`. So to set it as default on the command line, use:

```
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=net.sourceforge.napkinlaf.NapkinLookAndFeel
```

To install it add `napkinlaf.jar` to the `lib/ext` direction and the lines:

```
swing.installedlafs=napkin
swing.installedlaf.napkin.name=Napkin
swing.installedlaf.napkin.class=net.sourceforge.napkinlaf.NapkinLookAndFeel
```

to `lib/swing.properties` within your Java installation (you'll probably have to create the file).

See the [Napkin wiki page](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Projects/NapkinLAF)

Answer (score 9):

This page explains how the work with Look&Feels:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

You can do it commandline:

```
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel MyApp
```

Or in code:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
```

You need to make sure the jars containing the look&feel are on the application classpath. How this works depends on the application. A typical way would be to put it in a lib folder.

Look&Feels that are available by default in the JDK are:

```
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
```

Quioting the link above:

> The GTK+ L&F will only run on UNIX or
>   Linux systems with GTK+ 2.2 or later
>   installed, while the Windows L&F runs
>   only on Windows systems. Like the Java
>   (Metal) L&F, the Motif L&F will run on
>   any platform.

Comment: i know how to use LAF , but i want install LAF files .
and the GTK LAF not installed by default .

Comment: @Waseem -- Then I suggest you elaborate in your question.

Answer (score -2):

The Qt look and feel is available from [Trolltech](http://trolltech.com/) as the product Jambi, which IS Qt for Java.

Comment: this is no look and feel. it is the whole toolkit.