# Alternate Java GUI Frameworks

Tags: java, user-interface, frameworks

I am making a small game number game in Java (Nim) in OS X and was thinking about trying to make the GUI interface of the game using something other than Swing. I looked at SWT, but I read somewhere that SWT has some problems with OS X. I also looked at GTK+ bindings for Java, but I am not sure if that's a good choice either. Do you guys have any suggestions for a good Java GUI Framework that would look good and be compatible with OS X ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It depends, with eclipse 3.4, SWT 3.4 is quite supported with [MacOs](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/).

[image]

Now, SWT is OS specific, and you may not have the same flexibility than Swing, so you need to have good reason for looking for an alternative to Swing, especially when you consider there are good [LAFs (look and feel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145972/how-can-i-setup-lookandfeel-files-in-java) for java.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [JavaFX 2.0](http://javafx.com/).

Still early days but it looks quite promising for the kind of interactive / graphical applications that you might otherwise use Flash for.